# Stellar scalability to 4000 tx/s

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, performance

I tried to scale Stellar Standalone to process 4000 tx per second.

I use AWS EC2 m4.large for Core, and Horizon. Also I use Postgres RDS for core and Horrizon, but I have only 560 tx per second. My instance reaches only 10% of CPU load. I had just 180 stable connections on the instance.

Can anyone please advise on best practices and how I can improve/maximize the performance?

Comment: Your original question asked for contact details on skype etc. You can try speaking directly with other devs at https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public

Comment: Could you state the changes (if any) that you have already made to achieve the 560tps? Also the details of your OS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of performance improvements you can make over your current setup to improve performance. The top one is to move to a local database that you access over unix sockets rather than an RDS instance. See the stellar-core [performance guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/performance.html) for a complete rundown.